# add a button to a block

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I am very new to drupal and need some assistance.  I created a view for a news blog.  I want members to be able to be able to create news blogs, which would have to go through an approval process before being displayed.  I wanted to add a button called "create" or whatnot to my view which would allow the user to submit a news blog entry that would go to an approval queue to allow a moderator to edit before publishing.  This is not a regular blog (which don't need moderated).  It is specific to a "news blog" which is how we are referring to it. What is the best way of accomplishing this work flow and how would I go about creating the button?

Answer (score 0):

In Views, you have the option of adding a header and/or footer to your view.  It gives you a textarea which you select what filter you want to use (Full HTML, PHP code, etc).  I would suggest utilizing a header/footer and adding an image as a simple HTML link to the blog creation page.

As for your workflow, I would suggest taking a look at:

- [Workflow](http://drupal.org/project/workflow)
- [Content Moderation](http://drupal.org/project/content_moderation)
- [Revisioning](http://drupal.org/project/revisioning)
- [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules)

Here is an example to get a workflow going with the Rules module: http://drupal.org/node/550716